# how to upgrade couchdb in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, couchdb

I am using couchdb V1.4.0 on my ubuntu13.10.

I want to upgrade it to latest version with all data.

How can I do these without losing any data?

Thanks,
Nirmal

Comment: See here: http://serverfault.com/questions/139084/upgrade-default-install-of-couchdb-on-ubuntu-10-04

Answer (score -2):

Just upgrade to 1.6.1, it can read all old data files from 1.4.0. No upgrade needed.

Comment: This is a poor answer. *Just upgrade to ... no upgrade needed*. Then no explanation as to how this upgrade should be performed.

Comment: Fair enough! What I meant is that you can install 1.6.1 over a 1.4.0 installation, restart CouchDB, and everything continues to work. For exact install details, please refer to CouchDB's INSTALL file.

Comment: Jan, you might consider updating your answer to reflect your Dec 4, 16 comment.